# systemd ExecStartPost doesn't look to be called

Tags: systemd

I used the following config to start `beanstalkd` process

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/beanstalkd 
ExecStartPost=pgrep beanstalkd > /var/run/beanstalkd.pid
```

The last line is supposed to generate a pidfile after the process in launched, but the file is not created. why ?

Or is there another way to force pidfile creation in `systemd` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

systemd does not require a pidfile for a Type=simple service. It will manage the daemon in the foreground. `systemctl status SERVICE_NAME` will show the pid of the main process (and of any other processes in the cgroup).

For completeness, your ExecStartPost line did not work because systemd does not use a shell to execute commands and does not perform $PATH lookup, so you would have to use `ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "..."`, but as I said, the line is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you it works. I know `systemd` doesn't need a pidfile, but i'd like to generate one to monitor process with `monit`

Answer (score 3):

In case you still need an answer on this (or someone else does), you need a shell context to run pgrep, so the correct command would be

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/zsh -c 'pgrep process_name > /var/run/process_name.pid'
```

Comment: I recommend using "sh" since it can do everything required and is more commonly available `ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'pgrep process_name > /var/run/process_name.pid'`

Answer (score 0):

This shows the order of execs is from BOTTOM to TOP
http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-July/153897.html
Your ExecStartPost is running before ExecStart

Comment: The post you link points out that the ordering is inverted **in the status output**, not that it's actually temporally inverse. `ExecStartPre` happens before `ExecStart`, and `ExecStartPost` happens after.